# Select blocking issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

The database was not responding to simple select statements like

```
select * from table
```

I noticed in `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` that one session is blocking, blocking session was pointing to a stored procedure which use lock & Tran like below

```
    BEGIN TRAN

declare @min numeric ,@com numeric

select top 1  @com=companyid from tblcompanies
order by newid()



select @min=min(productid) from tblproducts(UPDLOCK)
where companyid=@com and (lockstatus<>1 or lockstatus is null )


update tblproducts
set lockStatus='1'
where productid>=@min and productid<@min+4

select distinct top 4 s.productname,s.productid,s.companyid,r.Type,r.requestType,r.UserID
from tblcompanydetail rd inner join tblproducts s
on rd.productid=s.productid
inner join tblcompanies r
on r.companyid=s.companyid
where s.productid>=@min and s.productid<@min+4


if @@error >0 rollback tran

commit tran
```

Please advise me if I have written it wrong.

Comment: How long was this procedure blocking your select? Are you sure it wasn't wrapped in a larger transaction (there are no autonomous transactions in SQL Server, so the commit here wouldn't truly commit an encapsulating one).

Comment: I have reposted my procedure, I missed on statement before

Comment: Problem has started few days ago, companies has around 3000 records, products has around 60000 & tblcompanydetail has around 240,000 records.

Comment: Can you explain the point of the procedure? To return 4 rows from a random company to the user, and then what?

Comment: We have software which scrape info for product like images, data from forum etc. SOftware run 24 hours

Comment: So the answer to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740437/sql-server-select-queries-very-slow)([s](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30276/simple-queries-run-slowly)) was not to [export/import the entire database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13777995/333564) then? Awesome.

Comment: @Mark Storey-Smith  It worked for few hours but again issue raised. Perhaps, locks were removed by detaching & attaching

Comment: Well yeah, detaching the database kind of kicks out all of the users. If you keep it detached, the problem won't come back, either.

Comment: @shawnswanson: Just curious, what's the tables' design if you have more details about companies than products (in avg you have 80 'company details' and 20 products per each company)?

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I would re-write this. Various comments inline. These changes may help reduce blocking but it's really hard to see how even the original would block for very long unless these are all heaps and/or every table access yields a scan...

```
DECLARE @min INT, @com INT; -- these are INTs, right?

SELECT TOP 1 @com = companyid 
  FROM dbo.tblcompanies -- always use schema prefix
  ORDER BY NEWID(); -- random company? really?

-- Minimize transaction duration. Any real need to select the 
-- random company & perform final select inside the transaction?

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  BEGIN TRY    

    SELECT @min = MIN(productid) 
      FROM dbo.tblproducts WITH (UPDLOCK)
      WHERE companyid = @com 
      AND (lockstatus <> 1 OR lockstatus IS NULL);

    UPDATE dbo.tblproducts
      SET lockStatus = '1' -- is this column numeric or string?
      WHERE productid >= @min AND productid < @min + 4; -- values guaranteed contiguous?

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    SELECT -- don't believe DISTINCT or TOP are required here
      s.productname, s.productid,   s.companyid,
      r.Type,        r.requestType, r.UserID  
    FROM dbo.tblproducts AS s
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblcompanies AS r
      ON r.companyid = s.companyid
    WHERE s.productid >= @min AND s.productid < @min + 4
    AND EXISTS -- since no columns from rd are needed
    ( 
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tblcompanydetail
      WHERE productid = s.productid
    );

  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  END CATCH
```

Comment: Do you think, changing query like this can help fixing issue? Is issue related to query written in different way?

Comment: Yes, this should reduce blocking, but I have no way of knowing how much (or why there is so much blocking in the first place).

Comment: Is there a way to add timeout for UPDLOCK ??

Comment: @shawnswanson Um, no. Well, you can set limits on request time using various approaches (e.g. Resource Governor, [SET LOCK_TIMEOUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189470.aspx)) but doesn't feel right. Do you want to hold the lock for the duration of the transaction or not? Based on your questions I think there is a much more fundamental tuning problem here. Your troubleshooting approach is like dusting off the bumper to get better MPG. This lock really shouldn't be getting held long enough for you to need to set a timeout, and I think you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I am willing to avoid same situation. If I can use lock timeout then there will be no blocking. I guess!!

Comment: @shawnswanson: tuning is a step by step operation. Do what Aaron advised, change your code, test, test again (not in production), then, if nothing changes for the good, come back with details.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but a wrap-up package for our OP to read about locking and blocking in the SQL Server environment. These are great questions from our site with lots of good info, articles and great comments.

[Can I be automatically notified of prolonged blocking in SQL server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15108/can-i-be-automatically-notified-of-prolonged-blocking-in-sql-server)

[Database locking issues?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/database-locking-issues/)

[Justify NOT using (nolock) hint in every query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2684/justify-not-using-nolock-hint-in-every-query/)

[SQL Server - what isolation level for non-blocking select statements?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6698/sql-server-what-isolation-level-for-non-blocking-select-statements/)

[SQL Server: what should be done when a process is blocking another process?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4839/sql-server-what-should-be-done-when-a-process-is-blocking-another-process)

[sql server concurrency performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4307/sql-server-concurrency-performance)

[What is blocking and how does it happen?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4760/what-is-blocking-and-how-does-it-happen)

It's an extensive subject, maybe not very easy to grasp, but in the end, understanding it will provide only benefits for you and your databases.

PS: I ordered the questions purely on random order, not on relevance. All of them are nice (and a must, from my POV) to read.